# Font-size inconsistency when choose between tracking option

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

When we are choose between tracking the next privilege and tag badge menu in the **[Activity tab - REPUTATION](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity)** section, the font-size is not inconsistency in all over the Stack Exchange sites.

When we select the **Track my next privilege**, the font-size is not same as (less than) when we select the **Track a tag badge instead** option.

Screenshots for reference:

[image: Track a tag badge]

[image: Track my next privilege]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font-size issue in the tracker is fixed recently. Now the same font-size is applied for "Track my next privilege" and "Track a tag badge instead" text.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: font-size fixed]